# change ownership using Icacls on windows

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

On a windows 7 enterprise 64 bit OS - I want to change ownership of a  folder inherited to all sub-folders using ICACLS

I am logged in as standard user. The folder is owned by an administrator user, and I run the `icacls`as that elevated user's command prompt 
I am not all very privy with windows but I want to do this as standard user running an elevated `cmd` 
so this is what I tried and did not work

```
ICACLS name /setowner <computername>\adminuser
```

Before that I used `icacls` to  grant `F` to adminuser and it succeeded.
 What did not succeed is changing owner from the command prompt using `icacls` 
and the command prompt is from a user who owns the folder. So the folder owner is running `icacls` and making another user the owner.
I get this error 

`setowner No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 0 files`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem on Windows 2008 R2, I was trying to set ownership to Administrators, so after getting the same error, I check the users on the domain, and found out that Administrators is NOT a username or group for the domain, but for the PC/SERVER, so, what I did is instead of

```
ICACLS name /setowner <computername>\adminuser
```

simply did

```
ICACLS name /setowner adminuser
```

and it worked.